# checkbox inside ngFor, only first checkbox is getting selected & deselected everytime when clicking any other checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, checkbox

I have checkboxes inside a ngFor loop and when I click on any one of the checkboxes only the first one is getting checked & unchecked and updating only first one's status.

HTML template :

```
<div *ngFor="let num of count" class="m-b-20"> 
    <div class="checkbox"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="num.value" value="num.checked" [(ngModel)]="num.checked" (click)="clicked(num)" ngDefaultControl/> 
        <label for="check"></label> 
    </div>
    {{num.checked}} 
</div>
```

Comment: please, provide your template code.

Comment: Can your share the code what all you have tried so far?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let num of count" class="m-b-20">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="num.value" value="num.checked" [(ngModel)]="num.checked" (click)="clicked(num)" ngDefaultControl/>
        <label for="check"></label>
    </div>{{num.checked}}
</div>

Comment: This is my HTML code

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer including your code

Comment: This is more of a job for a reactive form than a template based one.

Comment: Id should be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check value for `name`, you've used different for each element: `num.value`. This should be the same so that it works:

```
<div *ngFor="let num of count" class="m-b-20">
    <div class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-list" [(ngModel)]="num.checked" (click)="clicked(num)" ngDefaultControl/> 
    <label for="check"></label> </div>{{num.checked}}
</div>
```

checkbox-list is the new name

Comment: I changed the name but I still have the same issue. I tried printing the num sent by click function in console, it's sending first value only instead of the one I clicked on.

Comment: First of all print all values, without creating checkboxes, does it returns the full list?

Comment: Ok I've reviewed the code and ID wasn't unique, now it's fixed. Check console for errors, the ID problem should be warned there

Comment: Changing the ID makes checkbox unclickable.

Comment: Hey it worked! I just made ID unique as you said like id="check_{{i}}", and I need to change it in <label> tag as well like <lable for="check_{{i}}"> . Where i is the index.

Comment: As I've seen my answer was not accepted... understood!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having the same name for the checkboxes. On iterating try to give different names to the checkbox. It will work.

Comment: The problem is with the same id to all the checkboxes. Make the id also unique. Make it id="check_{{i}}", where you need to declare index like  *ngFor="let num of count;let i=index"

Comment: Hey worked! I just changed the ID and it worked. I had to change it in label tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

First remove id and value atttribute from your code.

```
<div *ngFor="let num of count" class="m-b-20">
<div class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-list" [(ngModel)]="num.checked" [checked]="num.checked==true" (click)="clicked(num)" ngDefaultControl/> 
<label for="check"></label> </div>{{num.checked}}
```

this atttribute doesn't need if you are using`[(ngModel)]` in checkbox. check this will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in Angular 6/ Bootstrap 4. 
When clicking on label, it would not check the checkbox. When clicking on checkbox, it would work, but clicking on label, it would not work.

Posting my solution here for future reference.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
     <div class="col-5 col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group form-check">

        <!-- wrap the label around the checkbox -->
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="item_check" id="check_{{item.ID}}">
           {{item.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

So if you notice, I had to wrap the checkbox inside the label.

Answer (score 0):

bind the id in input tag, and for in label tag.

```html
<div *ngFor="let num of count" class="m-b-20">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-list" [id]="num.value" (click)="clicked(num)" ngDefaultControl/>
    <label [for]="num.value"></label>
  </div>
  {{num.checked}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that id is same for all of them , so dynamically add something to each row's id and for respectively then it will work